# Firebase variable becomes null after browser refresh Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to angular 2 and I have successfully implemented Firebase authentication which is based on email and password the user sets.

Once the user log in, the Firebase variable is initialized and can be accessed throughout the app however once the user is in the app and refreshes the page the Firebase variable becomes null.

My question is how can I maintain the Firebase state after refresh occurs. Tried the local storage approach but that seems to be not suitable. most of the relevant queries in SO are for AngularJS.

Any ideas?

Edit

Firebase is initialized in appcomponant.ts file

```
  firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'A******E',
  authDomain: 'e******m',
  databaseURL: 'h*****m',
  projectId: 'e******r',
  storageBucket: 'e******m',
messagingSenderId: '****93***'
});
```

In my login service I am using

```
  signInUser(email: string, password: string) {
return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

}

Once the user authenticated he is directed to a page called settings. In the settings component I would like to get the email of the authenticated user. this all goes well when the flow is userlogin-->settings page, firebase is not null.

Issue starts when the user is in the settings page a hit F5 to refresh the page, at that point Firebase object becomes null.

Comment: have you looked at https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 ?

Comment: Firebase persists the Auth state in localStorage. It should not be cleared on page refresh. What environment are you serving your app?

Comment: As bojeil says, auth state is automatically persisted. So it's likely a problem that is specific to your situation. Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) all we can do is speculate on the cause.

Comment: Added some code, the code itself is quite straight forward. As for the Auth state, if Firebase preserves the Auth state then how can I get the authenticated user details without causing the user to re login. Looking in the Firebase docs I didnt find any relevant method.

Answer (score 0):

User [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the token you receive back from firebase. To set in local storage you can do

```
localStorage.setItem('fireBaseToken', 'token');
```

then in your main app.component.ts check if the token exists if it does add it to your variable otherwise redirect user to login again.

**NOTE**

The Angular CLI by default should add "dom" to your **tsconfig.json** otherwise add it your self.